# If someone were to put really small objects 10x spaced on a background, would they see the objects or the background?

Tags: optics, vision, nanoscience, perception

If someone were to put a sheet full of 1 micron x 1 micron black squares as a grid on a white piece of paper, and spaced them 10 microns apart (up-down, left-right, obviously diagonal doesn't count), would someone looking at it from a normal distance see black or white? If white, would they be able to see the black at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is identical to the process called [halftoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halftone), which is used in print to give the illusion of greys with only black and white, or the illusion of full color with only 4 pigments.  You describe a pattern which is 1% covered with black cubes, and 99% open space, so it would appear to be the "1% black" color of grey.

It's pretty hard to distinguish 1% black from 0% black, unless you have some reference, so people most likely would not see it at all.  If you coated half of the paper this way, and left half uncovered, most people could distinguish the covered half as a faint grey.

Answer (score 1):

American pop artist [Roy Lichtenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Lichtenstein) made some relevant art:

[image]

**^Above, if you are close enough to the image, you can clearly see black dots on white background**

[image]

**^Same image, just resized... the face appears gray instead**

So in general, the answer to "How do black dots on white paper look?" will depend on viewing distance. More specifically, the [angular resolution of the human eye is around 0.03 degrees](http://stokes.byu.edu/teaching_resources/resolve.html). If you pick what you mean by "normal distance", you can calculate what the resulting resolution in microns would be (assuming that the 0.03 degree rule of thumb holds for said "normal distance").